# How to Connect PHP with Aerospike Database?

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce, aerospike-loader

Installed Aerospike community 6.0 version in Cent OS thru VM ware, using AQL I can insert and delete values.. Now i want to connect with php with Aerospike..
how it can be done thru aql..
can anyone please tell me the steps for installing php and connecting to aql

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things:

`AQL` - as you mentioned is a data browser for examination of the DB and a tool for lightweight administrative tasks for maintaining.

`PHP Client` - a client SDK which allows you to interact with Aerospike database using PHP.

I suggest you read the `Aerospike PHP Client` documentation where you can find useful information such as how to install, connect, read/write, query, see some examples and more:
https://github.com/aerospike-community/aerospike-client-php/wiki

Answer (score 1):

There’s a community supported PHP, which has been dormant for a long time. The best way to use Aerospike with languages that don’t have a client in active development is through the [REST Gateway](https://developer.aerospike.com/blog/rest-gateway-2.0).

It’s API reference is here https://aerospike.github.io/aerospike-rest-gateway/